# mostrar datos PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy tratando de mostrar algunos resultados usando PDO. Hasta ahora usaba `mysqli_conect()`para la conexión con la base de datos. Supongo que el error se encuentra al mostrar los resultados en el `foreach()´ Alguien sabría decirme cómo puedo corregir el fallo? Gracias de antemano"

Código:

```
<?php


try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:name.database.windows.net,1344; 
Database = my_db_name", "my_user_name", "my_password");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Prod_Usu, Prod_Tit, Prod_Fec FROM productos"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach($result as $row) { 
        echo $row['Prod_Usu'] . " - " . $row['Prod_Tit'] . " - " . 
    $row['Prod_Fec'] . "<br>";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: Debe recordar que `setFetchMode` como su nombre lo dice **establece el modo de obtención de resultados más no los obtiene**, le  falta añadir el `fetch` antes del `foreach` , de la forma `$result =  $stmt->fetch()`  y luego iterar sobre `$result`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debes utilizar [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) o [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) para recuperar los resultados.

```
<?php


try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:name.database.windows.net,1344;Database = my_db_name", "my_user_name", "my_password");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Prod_Usu, Prod_Tit, Prod_Fec FROM productos"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    /* creamos un while para optener fila a fila los refultados devueltos mediante fetch() */
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $row['Prod_Usu'] . " - " . $row['Prod_Tit'] . " - " .$row['Prod_Fec'] . "<br>";
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay **sólo una línea** de tu código que está mal.

Cambiando esto:

<s>`$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`</s>

por esto:

```
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

debería funcionar.

```
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:name.database.windows.net,1344; 
    Database = my_db_name", "my_user_name", "my_password");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Prod_Usu, Prod_Tit, Prod_Fec FROM productos"); 
        $stmt->execute();

        // set the resulting array to associative
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($result as $row) { 
            echo $row['Prod_Usu'] . " - " . $row['Prod_Tit'] . " - " . 
        $row['Prod_Fec'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;

    ?>
```

Luego, el conjunto de resultados se puede leer usando un bucle `foreach` o usando `while`.